# Change Apache httpd "Server:" HTTP header

Tags: http, apache-httpd

One of the HTTP headers that the [Apache `httpd`](http://httpd.apache.org/) sends back with response data is "Server". For example, my web server machine is relatively up-to-date Arch Linux.  It sends back headers closely resembling the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 17:19:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
Content-Length: 1149
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

I have `ServerSignature off` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but the "Server:" header still appears. I have experimented with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html).  I have it enabled, and I've tried a few things:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
Header set ProcessingTime "%D"
Header set Server BigJohn
</IfModule>
```

After stopping and starting `httpd` with the above configuration, the HTTP headers include something like `ProcessingTime: 1523`, but the "Server:" header line remains unchanged. So I know that "mod_headers" is installed and enabled, and working, but not as I desire.

I see that something called "mod_security" claims to do this, but I don't want all the rest of the baggage that mod_security carries with it.

**UPDATE:**

Once you get `mod_security` installed, you only need a few directives:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
SecRuleEngine on
ServerTokens Full
SecServerSignature "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"
</IfModule>
```

That's for `mod_security` 2.7.7

Comment: Have you restarted apache since changing the conf file? Also I've never seen the file called 'httpd.com', usually it's called 'httpd.conf'.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky - thanks for catching the misspelling. It is "httpd.conf" I do stop and start httpd after changing httpd.conf.

Comment: By setting `ServerTokens Min` I was also able to remove the loaded modules (e.g. `mod_fastcgi`) from the header response that appeared after the blank server name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The server ID/token header is controlled by "[ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens)" directive (provided by `mod_core`). Aside from modifying the Apache HTTPD source code, or using `mod_security` module, there is no other way to *fully* suppress the server ID header.

With the `mod_security` approach, you can disable all of the module's directives/functions in the `modsecurity.conf` file, and leverage only the server header ID directive without any additional "baggage."

Comment: This does work, thank you very much. I have to note that mod_security is not one of Arch Linux's ordinary packages. There's a PKGBUILD in the AUR, but it hasn't been updated since 2011 (as of April 12, 2014) and it references a really old version of mod_security. As always, your distro may vary.

Answer (score 31):

mod_security is great, but you don't really need it to achieve your goal.

after all mods have been included in `httpd.conf` you can simply unset the headers of your choosing. As stated in the comments, `mod_headers` needs to be enabled.

```
Header unset Server

# if the above doesn't work, set a default value
# use the keyword 'always' to set the header even with error'ed responses
# (e.g. if your app is down)
Header always set Server "No peeking!"

ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature

Comment: mod_sec is needed for a custom text to hide completely the work apache otherwise your solution is good and simple :)

Comment: This has no affect for me using Apache 2.2 (patched) on Centos 6.

Comment: In Apache 2.4, it is reported as Syntax error : *Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

Comment: @Raptor You have to install [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) with `sudo a2enmod headers`

Comment: `Header unset Server` does not work in Apache 2.2 and 2.4. Response headers still contains `Server: Apache`

Comment: @MarisB This is because the `ServerTokens` value is set to `prod` which is short for "product", as in the product name of the server. This is the minimum value that you can get without using mod_security

Answer (score 16):

Just updating this for people who are still looking. I was having trouble getting the Server line in the HTTP header changed. This advice should work for Debian branch distros with systemd and Apache 2.4.7. Specifically, I am using Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04.03. Some advice I found was to do

```
grep -Ri servertokens /etc/apache2
```

This led me to /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf where both ServerTokens and ServerSignature were specified. Therefore, any changes I was making to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf were being overwritten by the directives already specified in security.conf.

I simply changed the directives in security.conf and Apache started working as I wanted.

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

On the topic of Header unset Server, I found a bug report where the Apache devs said it is a won't fix issue. Apparently for them it is a philosophical issue, despite that the specification for HTTP/1.1, RFC 2616 authored in part by Tim Berners-Lee, saying that the Server tag is optional.

I really wanted to set the Server tag to "Unknown" to make our Qualys scans happy. So, I installed mod_security, now called libapache2-modsecurity, following [this DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu). Best of luck, I hope I helped for all you future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested something on Oracle HTTP Server 11.1.1.9 (which is built on Apache 2.2.22) that worked for me, to some extent..

Setting the "ServerTokens" to "none" seems to remove the "Server" header value, although the header itself keeps being sent in the response, but now it has a null value.

> ServerTokens none

The response header would look like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 07:02:45 GMT
>
> **Server:**
>
> Last-Modified: Sun, 27 Dec 2015 07:29:13 GMT
>
> .
>
> .

Comment: On Apache 2.2 stock, from Centos 6 repos, setting a value of "none" causes Apache to output all data.  For instance:  "Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips Phusion_Passenger/4.0.59 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1"

Comment: agree, you can't use `none` on latest Apache: `ServerTokens takes 1 argument: 'Prod(uctOnly)', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Min(imal)', 'OS', or 'Full'`